# how to call postback link of another element in jQuery on some other event?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Hi This is kind of peculiar requirement..

I am using asp.net and jQuery together

I have a link button as follows

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="displayBtn" runat="server" OnClick="displayBtn_Click" Text="Display 
Content"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I will hide this link button using

```
style="dipsly:none;"
```

and want to call the postback called by click of the asp link button using some other html element say a div.

```
<div id="invokeTest"> Click here </div>
```

I tried using

```
$('#invokeTest').click(function(){
  $('#<%=displayBtn.ClientID%>').click();
});
```

Any idea how could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `LinkButton` try using a `Button`:

```
<asp:Button ID="displayBtn" 
            runat="server" 
            OnClick="displayBtn_Click" 
            Text="Display Content" 
/>
```

Comment: i changed from link button to <asp:Button and called it with .trigger() like this

$('#<%=displayBtn.ClientID%>').trigger("click");

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#<%=displayBtn.ClientID%>').trigger("click");
```

See **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**